# WPF datagrid, зависимость ячейки DataGridCheckBoxColumn от DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Есть datagrid, который состоит из 2 колонок: первая - выпадающий список с элементами 1,2,3; и вторая - checkbox.
Как чекбоксу задать isEnable = False если в выпадающем списке выбрано 1

Comment: А сами то как пробовали? Ведь это весьма простая задачка то...

Comment: Я в этом деле недавно и вот на такой задачке и запнулся на самом простом

Comment: Ну вот вы для начала сами попробуйте, подумайте как эту задачу можно решить и уж потом, здесь спрашивайте, указав все ваши попытки. Поймите, если мы будем по каждому вашему простому вопросу давать ответы, то вы вряд-ли научитесь программированию. Вот распишу я сейчас подробно как и что, сделаю готовый пример, а вы мне в ответ "для меня это сложно, я не понимаю, но спасибо за решение" и вот что мой ответ вам даст? Да ничего, вы его скопируете подчистую, чуть подправите и пойдете дальше, не задумываясь как оно работает. Так что если учите, то пробуйте сами и уж потом спрашивайте, мы поможем.

Comment: Мне на примерах легче учится, т.к. я вижу что используется и как связывается.
у меня были варианты сделать через CellEditEnding, но такой вариант не подходит. Смотрел в инете, что можно как-то через xaml с помощью Style->Property->IsEnable (к столбцу 2) - но при этом варианте я не знаю как получить данные из столбца 1, сопоставить их и уже применить к столбцу 2 Value="false" или "true"

Comment: Если у вас грамотно реализована привязка, то ваша таблица, это будет простой класс, который будет содержать в себе свойство коллекции (этих 1,2,3), свойство выбранного объекта в коллекции, свойство для `CheckBox` (типа выбран или нет), ну и свойство для `IsEnabled`, которое вызывает INPC. Ну и логика будет такая: в Set свойства выбранного объекта делаем `IsEnabled = value != 1;`, все, вот и вся ваша логика, остается привязать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути задача очень простая и все тут зависит от того, как грамотно у вас сделано приложение, используются привязки и так далее.

Если по уму, то должен быть отдельный класс, который будет иметь информацию про одну строку в таблице, нечто на подобие этого:

```
public class Item : NotifyBase
{
    public List<int> Items { get; } = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

    private int selectedItem;
    public int SelectedItem
    {
        get => selectedItem;
        set
        {
            IsEnabled = value != 1;
            selectedItem = value;
        }
    }

    private bool isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled 
    {
        get => isEnabled;
        set => SetField(ref isEnabled, value);
    }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Это очень упрощенный вид и пару нюансов тут есть, но для  примера сойдет. Логика думаю вам понятна, мы имеет некое свойство `SelectedItem`, которое будет обновляться каждый раз, когда будет выбрано новое значение в `ComboBox`, а зная тот факт, что у свойств есть `get` (когда кто либо хочет получить данные из него) и `set` (когда кто либо хочет данные в него установить), то мы можем чуть переписать `set`, указав в нем простейшую логику с проверкой нового значения.
Так, как меняется свойство из кода (я про `IsEnabled = ...`), то нам надо сказать интерфейсу про это, оповестить его и для этих целей есть `INotifyPropertyChanged`, который и вызывается в `set` нужного свойства. Сама же реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` бывает разная, я использую эту:

```
public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string? propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Собственно вот и все, что надо для решения такой задачи, как у вас. Остается только сделать коллекцию для привязки, задать `DataContext` из которого XAML будет получать данные, ну и написать простенький интерфейс.
Я буду писать все прям в окне, но вам советую сделать отдельный класс для таких целей, окно же должно быть чистым!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; } = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item(),
        new Item(),
        new Item(),
        new Item(),
        new Item(),
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Ну и XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Значение" >
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />
                    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />
                    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Выбрано">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Ненавижу этот компонент, заставляет кучу лишнего писать, так что если знаете как лучше - дерзайте, я лишь написал на быструю руку.
Тут все довольно просто, мы делаем таблицу, привязываем ее к `Items` свойству, ну и делаем две колонки, где первая отображает список из цифр, а вторая это `CheckBox`.

Запускаем и видим то, что наша логика успешно отработала

[image: Result]

Как видите все довольно просто, удачи в изучении!

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Пошел разбираться как это работает ))